# Conflict in core-js versions

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, babeljs

I updated a project from core-js 2 to core-js 3. But since it still depends on babel-runtime DuplicatePackageCheckerPlugin throws an error:

`Failed to compile.
     [exec] core-js
     [exec]   Multiple versions of core-js found:
     [exec]     2.6.10 /~/babel-runtime/~/core-js from /~/babel-runtime/~/core-js/library/fn/array/from.js
     [exec]     3.4.0 /~/core-js from /~/core-js/modules/es.symbol.js`
Any suggestions on how to fix that?

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall the library and reinstall ?

Comment: yes,mulltiple times

Comment: Do you have babel in your package.json ?

Comment: As i remember, If you install Babel, it requires to install core-js. if you have both of them in package.json, it will install core-js twice. try remove core-js from your package.json and see what happens

Comment: And also, go to you project's node_modules, scroll down and see how many folders are there named core-js ?